# Specificity Error - CSS

Tags: css, css-specificity

So when calculating the specificity of some CSS code I came across with something I find contradictory.

According to the "formula" (inline > id > class > elements) I made the calculations for the couple of lines ahead:

```
(1)  p.b {color: red}          Specificity: (0,0,1,1)
(2)  .a>.c {color: black}                   (0,0,2,0)
```

Since (2) has 2 classes, its specificity is higher than (1) and therefore the browser should go for black instead of red, which happens exacly the other way around.

Can anyone give me some insight on what I'm doing wrong?

HTML CODE:

```css
/* Specificity: (0,0,1,1) */
p.b {
  color: red
}

/*              (0,0,2,0) */
.a>.c {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="c">
    <p class="b">Parágrafo 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is p.b the first child of .a and also having the class of .c? Can you show the html you're testing with in a fiddle?

Comment: @KaiQing I added the html code to the post

Comment: as @KaiQing pointed out, the `>` operator means 'direct descendant of'. Your 'c' is not a direct descendant of 'a'....Well one of them is, but the 1st and 3rd aren't...

Comment: @xdhmoore I'm referring to the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: My bad...Trying to go too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the second paragraph: out of your two selectors, the `.a > .c` selector only directly applies to the parent `<div class="c">` element.  Its styles are inherited if any other selectors don't override them.  but the `p.b` selector is the only one of the two that directly applies to the child `<p>` element with the text in it, so it takes precedence.  As another poster said, the specificity rules don't apply unless two selectors are targeting the same element.  Here they are targeting a parent and a child.  When deciding the styling for the child, the child's own selectors will always win over styles inherited from a parent.

Comment: Even though the other answers are also correct, marking this as the correct one considering it was the most understandable one. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle showing an example as you laid it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/zfd2a8et/1/

```
<div class="a">
    <p class="b">this should be red</p>
    <p class="b c">This should be black</p>
    <p>This has children <span class="c">which should be red because .a &gt; .c is selecting only the first level of children</span></p>
    <div class="c"> This should be black <p class="b"> and this should be red</p></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
p.b{
    color:red;
}

.a > .c{
    color:black;
}
```

the `>` selector is addressing direct descendants of `.a` so because your c is nested in b, the selector will not qualify. Your second paragraph indeed matches the `.a > .b` initially, but the `p.b` rule exists outside the scope of that selector since > is descendent directly and a child would not be affected

Answer (score 1):

The specificity applies when targeting the same element, not for inheritance from ascendant elements.

Your `p.b` applies to the `p` element with *Parágrafo 2* while the `.a > .c` applies to its container so there is no conflict to be resolved.